# debug mobile no access android app

Tags: android, debugging, mobile, android-studio

I created an app with this line

```
Settings.System.putFloat(getBaseContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.System.FONT_SCALE, (float) 10.0)
```

I executed it on my mobile phone and everything was nice. I disabled debug mode and I switched it off. When I woke up the following day, I started my mobile phone and the letters of my mobile phone were ten time larger and consequently, I cannot introduce my PIN and I cannot access to my mobile phone by removing my SIM card. So, I have no way to enable the debug option to execute an app with the line which would leave letters in their original way.

Does someone know how to save my device?

Comment: Factory reset. By hardware. Google on how to do that to your phone. Something like boot in rexovery mode or so. BTW which model-vendor??

Comment: Thank you eduyayo! I'm going to do that. It's a Sony Xperia E